# Passing javascript callback function name from rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the pageless jquery plugin and in my application helper I need to pass the name of the callback function as one of the parameters:

```
opts = {
        :totalPages => total_pages,
    :url        => url,
    :loaderMsg  => 'Loading more items...',
    :loaderImage => image_path("img/ajax_loader.gif"),
    :complete => "update"
}

javascript_tag("$('#tiles').pageless(#{opts.to_json});")
```

This doesn't work apparently because jquery tries calling "update".call()

How should I pass the name of my callback function so in json it'll be without quotations

Comment: Is it supposed to be a string?

Comment: no, It is just the name of the javascript function I have: function update().. I need to pass it to pageless jquery plugin so it will be called upon completion of the task. I don't know how to call it

Comment: The object passed to the jQuery function is expected to have a function object on `opts.complete`. JSON objects cannot contain function objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $('#tiles').pageless({
    totalPages: <%= total_pages %>,
    url: '<%= url %>',
    loaderMsg: 'Loading more items...',
    loaderImage: '<%= image_path("img/ajax_loader.gif") %>',
    complete: update
  });
<% end %>
```

If I'm correct in assuming your snippet comes from a Rails view.

Comment: It is comping from a _helper.rb

Comment: Should work there too. I'm assuming you're using ERB template engine. If it is something else, you'll need to translate.

Comment: I think I can do it the way you said but I thought there should be a way to pass javascript function names to to_json

Comment: I don't think so. You would need to `eval` the string in the client side with JavaScript to convert it from a string to a pointer to something in the scope of the JavaScript execution. As you're passing these options directly to pageless it doesn't seem possible (if pageless was to eval the string it would be in the context of pageless which likely doesn't have the `update` function in scope). [Here is the `complete` callback call in pageless](https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless/blob/master/lib/jquery.pageless.js#L194).